# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"

Tags: java, numberformatexception

"out.txt" content is

> 1

My JAVA code is like this.

```
    int val=0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("out.txt"));

    while(true) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        if (line==null) break;
        val=Integer.parseInt(line);
    }
    br.close();
```

and debugger says,

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "﻿1"

i need to use 1 from "out.txt".
How can i use 1 as Integer?
Thank you for your attention :)

Comment: Look at if there are any hidden special characters, white spaces etc.

Comment: there were no any hidden special characters :) but thank you to answer me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must be having the trailing whitespaces. Use the `trim()` function as follows:

```
val = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
int val = 0;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("out.txt"));

String line = null;
while(true) {
    line = br.readLine();
    if (line == null) break;
    val = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
}
br.close();
```

Also, if you want to check whether String is `null` or `empty` you can start using the Apache Commons `StringUtils` as follows:

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(line)) break;
```

Comment: I tried 'trim()' first but it didn't work ^^;; but thank you to answer me

Comment: oh! you save my day <3 Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

I removed this invisible Unicode character and now parsing to INT works great. I know it's not the case here but maybe can help some other people.

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\uFEFF", "");
```

Comment: Yep, this is the BOM. I had the exact same problem as the OP and it turned out I had exported a CSV file from Excel as _UTF-8 WITH BOM_. Java treated the BOM as part of the input. I re-exported to a different encoding and the problem was solved. [BOM on WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Answer (score -1):

Did you create the file on a Mac? Probably there is some hidden character. You can create it on Windows and try again.

Answer (score -2):

Oops. Yesterday the following code worked well so i uploaded it as you are seeing. but today, i tried compile one more time **without '.toString()' and well, it worked too.** So It was my mistake and I'm sorry to bother you guys.
(I don't know why it didn't work without '.toString' exactly the day before yesterday.)

---

Thank you so much people who cared of my question but i found the answer(i don't know how to find it by myself)

following codes work very well :) Thank you!

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("out.txt"));
    int val=0;

    while(true) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        if (line==null) break;
        val=Integer.parseInt(line.toString());
    }
    br.close();
```

Comment: `line` is already a String! What do you think will happen if you do `toString()` on it?

Comment: This doesnt make sense